History and origin of the idea of Frame of reference
How come the idea of the frame of reference even hit to the early scientists? Alongside the intuition involved behind it, I most definitely need a detailed research paper or some reference behind.

Related perhaps is: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15379/where-does-motion-happen-for-galileo
a general remark is that, an "idea" is different from the formal definition of a concept. In this case, like many others, the idea is probably much older than its precise mathematical formulation.

Potential sources here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/when-were-fictitious-forces-introduced/1828#1828

The idea of the frame of reference hit the early scientists only vaguely, they had no clear concept of it. Relativity of motion was discussed informally, as in Galileo's dialogs or Principia, but in terms of experienced perspective rather than some structured geometry. Although "generalized coordinates" that appeared in the works of d'Alembert, Euler, Lagrange and Hamilton are today interpreted in terms of reference frames, back then they were just formal mathematical devices. Newton's absolute space framework was dominant and it made other frames as separate entities redundant.
Systematic reflections on reference as a physical concept and its effect on physical laws only appeared in the second half of 19th century. The term "reference frame" was introduced by James Thomson (older brother of the better known William Thomson, lord Kelvin) only in 1884. Lange independently introduced a similar concept of "inertial system" in 1885. This fed into the prior debates about the "true meaning" of mechanical laws, with Mach, among others, systematically challenging absolute space conceptions in his Die Mechanik in ihrer Entwickelung (1883) that influenced Einstein. Some of Mach's reflections on inertial frames were arguably anticipated by Kant in his analysis of the universal gravitation and the role of fixed stars. The genesis of the modern reference frame concept is reviewed in DiSalle, Conventionalism and the Origins of the Inertial Frame Concept:

"As far as Newtonian mechanics is concerned, this problem was essentially solved
by James Thomson in 1884, when he introduced the term "reference frame" and defined
what we now call the inertial frame. His insight was that the laws of motion
themselves postulate certain spatial and temporal structures, or, in his words, a certain
kind ofreference-frame and "dial-traveler" (time scale). He therefore proposed a
"Law of Inertia," which I paraphrase: for any system of interacting bodies, it is possible
to construct a reference-frame and a time scale with respect to which all accelerations
are proportional to, and in the direction of, impressed forces.  Yet the end of the nineteenth century saw, not a recognition of the clarification
that had been achieved, but an often bewildering philosophical debate over Newton's
laws and the reference frame that they require, a debate that continued even after special
relativity might have made the issues seem outdated. This is because to many of
the participants in that debate, the (now seemingly straightforward) problem that
Thomson addressed inevitably raised philosophical issues that affected the foundations
of mechanics. Thus Ludwig Lange, for example, independently recapitulated
Thomson's work (more or less) in his definition of "inertial system" (Lange 1885),
but, while Thomson modestly thought he had clarified a point in Newtonian mechanics,
Lange thought that he had set Newton's laws on an entirely new footing - a footing
that purportedly replaced absolute notions with relative, real with ideal, and, especially,
factual with conventional.  Lange developed his concept of inertial system from precedents in the German literature
on the foundations of physics, especially Carl Neumann (1870), Heinrich Streintz
(1883), and Ernst Mach (1883). Taking it as a basic principle that all motion is relative,
these authors held that the classical law of inertia raised the fundamental "problem of
the reference-system": relative to what system of reference is the motion of a free body
rectilinear, and relative to what time-scale is it uniform? More generally, relative to
what do the laws of motion hold? Neumann's infamous "Alpha body" was his answer
to this question: he postulated that "at an unknown place in the cosmos," beyond our
observation, sits a rigid and unchanging body, and that relative to this "Alpha-body" the
motion of a free body is rectilinear (1870, p. 15). Streintz, attempting to improve on
Neumann, proposed that the law of inertia holds with respect to any body found to be
free of external forces, and named the appropriate reference-bodies "fundamental bodies."
Both approaches had serious difficulties (see DiSalle 1988, especially chapter III),
but the questions they were designed to answer seemed unavoidable once Newton's theory
of absolute space was recognized to be unsatisfactory.  As Thomson's work shows, however, these questions are not really appropriate.
The laws of motion do not hold "relative to inertial systems," or relative to anything.
Again, by claiming that accelerations occur only in the presence of forces, the laws of
motion assert the possibility of constructing systems in which every acceleration is
traced to an interaction - in other words, they assert that inertial systems exist - and
so one can't sensibly say that the laws are true only in such frames. True or false, the
laws make frame-independent claims about the distinction between free motion and
motion influenced by interactions. Ernst Mach recognized this when he pointed out
that we could state the laws of motion without specifying any frame of reference at
all, since the laws enable us to find a suitable frame (Mach 1883, p. 269); his chief
objection to the laws was not that they are essentially relative, but that all of the evidence
for them comes from motions relative to the fixed stars, and so there is no empirical reason to regard them as anything more than an inductive generalization about
those relative motions."


Frames of reference have their origin in the work of Galilei and Huygens. The work of Galilei is much better known to the general public than that of Huygens:
The motion of colliding bodies, there is an English translation in Isis, Vol. 68, No. 4 (Dec., 1977), pp. 574-597.
